# Firebase rules with Bolt compiler

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm using the Firebase Bolt compiler to generate rules and I've noticed that read and write ones that it generates are different.

I wrote a function that looks at a certain node to see if there's valid data there.  I then use that function in a different section.

So the function is something like

```
isValidInvite(r_id, invite_id) = root['invites'][r_id][invite_id] != null;
```

and when I use it :

```
read() = isValidInvite($resource_id, $invite_id);
write() =isValidInvite($resource_id, $invite_id);
```

The json that Bolt generates is

```
".read": "root.child('invites').child($resource_id).child($invite_id).val() != null",
".write":"newData.parent().parent().parent().parent().child('invites').child($resource_id).child($invite_id).val() != null"
```

I believe both are equivalent right?  Go look at a certain node and make sure there's data there.
"write" takes the long way to get to the same node.  Up the tree and back down.
The rules work and I wont actually be using the same function for both read and write but I'm trying to understand Firebase rules and Bolt a little better.

BTW, I can't imagine writing rules without Bolt after using only a short while.  Huge step up from trying to do it by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See discussion here https://github.com/firebase/bolt/issues/87:

The reason is subtle (not obvious):  To support multi-location updates, you need to be able to write rules that will refer to the "new" value of the date.  The standard in Bolt is that in write and validation rules, `this` and `root` references are newData values (in read rules, this and root are `data` - old/existing - values).

Ideally, we would have a `newRoot` variable in JSON rules - so we could transform `root` to `newRoot` in those cases.  Since we don't (yet), Bolt generates the equivalent rules using newData.parent().... (i.e. a relative reference to the newData).

If you are not using multi-location updates, and you want Bolt to generate a simpler rule, you can use `prior(root)` instead of `root`.

Comment: I thought it might be a new vs existing thing.  Thanks for the explanation.  Do you know if Bolt supports or will support having comments carry over to the json?